# Uniformizing a relation on ordered sets

Tags: set-theory, terminology, order-theory, lattice-theory

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are (complete) ordered sets. Suppose $R\subseteq A\times B$, and

$f(a)=\inf\{b : (a,b)\in R\}$

$g(b)=\inf\{a : (a,b)\in R\}$

then what can we call $f$ and $g$? Perhaps there is some standard terminology.

Comment: [Antitone Galois connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection)? (At least in some cases.)

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{N}$ is not complete with respect to the usual ordering $\leq$ because $\mathbb{N}$ does not have a supremum.

Comment: Since he only takes infimums, he only needs lower semi-complete.

Comment: I don't know any standard terminology for this, but I would likely refer to $f$ as the lower boundary of $R$ and $g$ as the left boundary. If the order also had supremums, then there would also be a corresponding upper boundary and right boundary.

Comment: Thanks @JoelDavidHamkins in general that sounds good (in my case of interest $R$ is upward closed in the product order).

Comment: But I also like "lower envelope" and "left envelope", since these functions are the envelopes of the collection of all uniformizations (even computable partial uniformizations) of $R$.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais it would be interesting if you post an answer including how you thought of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maps $f,g$ constitute a Galois connection, but you have to take $\leq := \supseteq$ in both cases.

Comment: Or maybe $\ge $?